# How to fix "Does not exist" when calling a static function from another class?

Tags: c#

I want to call a static void function from another class, but it's said

> The name [funcion name here] does not exist in the current context

Each class is in the same project, `Framework 4.5.2`
Its a `public static void` Function, in a `public static class`, don't see why it's not working.

*The class where a **function located**, I want to call:*

```
namespace Client.Modules
{
    public static class Login 
    {

        public static void Run()
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

*The class where I want **to call**:*

```
using Client.Modules;

namespace Client
{
    public class Main
    {
        Login.Run(); // here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public class Main
{
    Login.Run(); // here
}
```

That’s invalid: You can’t generally execute code outside methods. The only things that can go directly into classes are declarations. Put `Login.Run()` inside a method.

Comment: Ooo, I see! It's working, thnaks sir.

        `public Main()
        {
            Login.Run();
        }`